# Handling Nested Promise Function Calls

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise

If I have a function that gets an api response and awaits it, like this:

```
async function getResponse(repo) {
  const apiResponse = await axios.get(...); // uses repo
  return apiResponse;
}
```

and I have a function that applies this function to many repos:

```
async function getResponsesMany(repos) {
  const promises = [];
  repos.forEach(repo => promises.push(getResponse(repo));
  const responses = await Promise.all(promises);
  return responses;
}
```

I can get all my data like this:

`const allData = await getResponsesMany(myRepos);`

But this is weird to me, because `getResponse` is awaiting the `axios.get` call, but I feel like I don't need to do that, since when I `await Promise.all(promises)` it will handle any nested promises. Am I supposed to therefore refactor `getResponse` to return the promise returned by `axios.get` instead? Is there a reason one should be faster than the other?

Comment: There's no point `await`ing in `getResponse` as written, no. Fundamentally it still returns a promise of the result of calling `axios.get`, as calling `axios.get` already does, so you could just `return axios.get(...)` (and then it doesn't even need to be `async`). Also it's unnecessary to create an empty array, push a bunch of promises into it then `await` the result - just `await Promise.all(repos.map(...))`.

Comment: thanks feel free to leave a response and I can accept it.

Comment: `nested promises`,  there are no nested promises here, just a list of promises..  Nested would imply the result of previous promises are required for deeper ones..

Comment: `getResponsesMany` returns a promise containing promises, no?

Comment: Well yes, that's how promises work, and why you see the term promise chain.  The term nesting maybe threw me..

Comment: I think I understand what you're saying, and I was using nesting in a more uncommon way / not what is normally used

Comment: Arguably you don't even have to await the Promise.all, just return it since you need to await `getResponsesMany` anyway.

Comment: right, I see, I'm starting to see the pattern of how to use them now, thanks

Comment: @Keith technically since `getResponse` is an `async` function, omitting the `await` makes the returned promise be resolved with the axios promise, which you might consider "nesting". One could however drop the `async` marker when there's no `await` left in the function :-)

Comment: @713sean No, `getResponsesMany` does not return a promise containing promises. It returns a promise for an array of values.